# Can't append column values to a list using a conditional statement

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'product':['shoe','shirt','pants','socks'],
                   'review_rating':[1.2,3.0,4.0,2.1],
                   'review_text':['good','bad','good','bad']})
good_reviews = []
print(df)
```

I want to be able to append my review_text values to the list using a conditional statement.

I tried this:

```
for column in df[['reviews.rating', 'reviews.text']]:
    if df[df['reviews.rating']] <= 2.0:
        good_reviews.append(df['reviews.text'])
```

After trying that I got an error:

> KeyError: None of [Index(['reviews.rating', 'reviews.text'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'product':['shoe','shirt','pants','socks'],
                   'review_rating':[1.2,3.0,4.0,2.1],
                   'review_text':['good','bad','good','bad']})

good_reviews = df.loc[df["review_rating"] <= 2.0,'review_text']

print(good_review)
```